# list of dates, how to get count of individual quarters

Tags: python

i have list of date, how to get count of individual quarters `1Q2015 2Q2015 3Q2015 4Q2015 1Q2016 2Q2016 3Q2016 4Q2016 1Q2017 2Q2017`

```
list of data

10    1Q2016
11    1Q2017
12    1Q2015
13    1Q2016
14    1Q2016
15    2Q2017
16    1Q2016
17    4Q2016
18    1Q2016
19    4Q2017
20    1Q2016
21    1Q2016
22    1Q2016
23    1Q2016
24    1Q2016
25    1Q2016
26    1Q2016
27    1Q2016
28    1Q2016
29    1Q2016
   ...  
53    2Q2016
54    2Q2015
55    2Q2016
56    2Q2016
57    2Q2017
58    2Q2016
59    2Q2016
```

how to split them into sublist of `1Q2015 2Q2015 3Q2015 4Q2015 1Q2016 2Q2016 3Q2016 4Q2016 1Q2017 2Q2017`

I am new to python

it worked with below code

```
from collections import Counter
pidx2 = Counter((quarter))
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/. Also post proper data, either copy'n'pastable Python data structures or clearly distinguish file contents and console input.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please, note that the Snippet below is based on a couple of Assumptions: [ that is; working with the *"not-so-complete information"* you posted ].

Assume for an instant that your Data is contained in a File (csv, txt or whatsoever). Then to count the number of times an individual Keyword (ex: `1Q2016`) appears in the list, You may need to import the File and then process it like the Snippet below suggests:

**CONTENTS OF THE FILE: (data.txt)**

```
10    1Q2016
11    1Q2017
12    1Q2015
13    1Q2016
14    1Q2016
15    2Q2017
16    1Q2016
17    4Q2016
18    1Q2016
19    4Q2017
20    1Q2016
21    1Q2016
22    1Q2016
23    1Q2016
24    1Q2016
25    1Q2016
26    1Q2016
27    1Q2016
28    1Q2016
29    1Q2016
53    2Q2016
54    2Q2015
55    2Q2016
56    2Q2016
57    2Q2017
58    2Q2016
59    2Q2016
```

**THE SNIPPET FOR COUNTING THE OCCURRENCES:**

```
fileContainingData  = 'data.txt'    # PATH/TO/FILE/WITH/DATA
fHandle             = open(fileContainingData, 'r')
dictData            = {}

for line in fHandle.readlines():
    # SPLIT THE LINE USING EMPTY SPACE AS DELIMITER
    lParts              = list(filter(lambda v: v.strip(),line.split(sep=" ")))
    key                 = str(lParts[1]).strip("\n ")
    if key not in dictData.keys():
        dictData[key]   = 1
    else:
        dictData[key]  += 1

fHandle.close()

print(dictData)
# YIELDS: 
# {
#  '1Q2016': 15, 
#  '1Q2017': 1, 
#  '1Q2015': 1, 
#  '2Q2017': 2, 
#  '4Q2016': 1, 
#  '4Q2017': 1, 
#  '2Q2016': 5, 
#  '2Q2015': 1
#  }
```

Hope that's close enough...
Cheers and Good-Luck ;-)